# Property field in a django model is not serialized. How to fix?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    return 'files/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.username, filename)

class File(models.Model):
    fid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

when I try to serialize this model using for example `serializers.serialize('json', File.objects.all())` I get:

```
u'[{"model": "app_name.file", "pk": "45f616b4-d028-488e-83c5-878ce1028018", "fields": {"user": 1, "file": "files/username/filename.txt"}}]'
```

I want the serialized json to also include the file field's url which `file_obj.file.url` returns so I added a property field like so:

```
class File(models.Model):
    fid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)

    def _get_file_url(self):
        "Returns file's url"
        return self.file.url
    url = property(_get_file_url)
```

However property field `url` is still not serialized. So I tried to write a custom serializer for the model by extending `serializers.ModelSerializer` like so:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('fid', 'user', 'file', 'url')
```

which doesn't work and I get `'module' object has no attribute 'ModelSerializer'`. is it because django doesn't have ModelSerializer class and only django rest_framwork does ? if so how do I solve this if I am using django only and not django rest framework ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show full content of file where you declare class FileSerializer?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner do you mean to see if `serializers` is imported ? if so yes I have the following statement in the file: `from django.core import serializers`

Comment: This is wrong. Django core serializers module doen't have ModelSerializer class. It's part of Django rest framework library. You should install it and use `from rest_framework import serializers`import.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner thanks. That's what I have asked in the question. Is there a way to achieve this without having to use rest_framework ?

Comment: @YasirJan see my answer. This should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

### when not using DRF - what is a poor idea...

you have to build manually in your view the dict with the data you wish to return and then use `from django.http.response import JsonResponse` for serializing the result.

```
def single_object_representation(obj):
    return  {
        'fid': obj.fid,
        'user': obj.user.username,
        'url': obj._get_file_url()
    }

def demo_view(request):
    objects_to_serialize = File.objects.all()

    result = [single_object_representation(obj) for obj in objects_to_serialize]
    return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

### using django.core.serializers

see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

but make sure it will work with your property. For some fields like User you should use duble underscore notation `__` e.g `user__username`

### otherwise (with DRF) - what I strongly recommend to you

First of all install drf:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

Then if there is still problem with your serializer give a try to the `SerializerMethodField` (if in doubt see the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('fid', 'user', 'file', 'url')

    def get_url(self):
        return self. _get_file_url()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realize that this is achievable using django rest framework. However I am looking for a solution that doesn't require drf.

Comment: I think you should accept that answer because you asked for drf based solution and used the tag of drf... and eventually ask a seperate question. BTW drf is the right tool for that.

Comment: My question specifically asks for a non drf solution: " if so how do I solve this if I am using django only and not django rest framework ?"

Comment: I'll remove the tag if you insist.

Comment: @YasirJan see my updated answer with poor django solution

Comment: @YasirJan does it works for you? If so please accept the answer.

Comment: yes I already know that I can do this manually without using serializers. If I can't find a serializers based answer I will accept yours.

Comment: @YasirJan see update with usage of `django.core.serializers`